# Does ANCS allow for a BLE device to send it a notification?

Tags: ancs

The `ANCS` documentation provides information on how a `BLE NP` can receive notifications when paired.  Is it possible for a `BLE` device (CC2540) to send a notification to an `iOS` device without having to install an App?  Basically I want to have the `BLE` act like the iphone in the `Notifyr` App, without having any app loaded.

Is this possible with iOS 8 or do you still need to have a third party App loaded?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

No,

You do not need any application at Notification Provider device so in this case it is iOS device. You just have to program Notification consumer side, e.g. Wearable. For more detail on this you may check [this Blog post](http://blog.punchthrough.com/post/63658238857/the-apple-notification-center-service-or-wtf-is)

> No coding required
>
> You do not need to write any iOS code to take
> advantage of ANCS. Your NC device can use what is known as “Service
> Solicitation” to indicate to the NP what services it would like to use
> on the NP once connected. Doing this should place your device in the
> Bluetooth Devices list in Settings. Your NP device can now be
> connected to manually by the user. Once connected, the NC device uses
> the client role to discover and subscribe to ANCS notifications.

and for your last Question

> Is this possible with iOS 8 or do you still need to have a third party
> App loaded?

Yes its Possible.

Answer (score 0):

you don't need  to  have a third party App loaded

about the coding of CC2540， you can prefer to  the below link

http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/Cc2640_ANCS_Sample